# Angular UI's $StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, state, internet, routing

I was thinking of using Angular UI, and specifically its `$StateProvider`, which makes it easy to create nested views, in my next application. Until now, I have been using vanilla Angular's `ngInclude` directive with a URL as a variable passed in from some controller. This is easy enough, but, as you can imagine, it can get pretty complex, and the `uiView` directive promises to make it simple.

One thing I keep coming back to as a reason not to use `$StateProvider` is the "state" part. The Internet is supposed to be "stateless", yet this is an entire routing system built on providing "states" to your site. It feels wrong. I know we have things like cookies and sessions that provide a kind of pseudo-statefulness, but these were kind of needed and they aren't a full system like `$StateProvider`. Also, state may not necessarily be a bad thing for the Internet. I tend to think it is, but I can see why some programmers might want it.

On the other hand, the states provided by `$StateProvider` don't seem like the kind of states the Internet isn't meant to have. When I think of "statefulness" in terms of the Internet, I think of initial state, not inherent state. If you do some action on a website, and then GET a resource again through the same path (URI), then the resource you get should be the same resource, though it might be changed or deleted. `$StateProvider` does not seem to violate this principle because you're GETting the same resource each time you go to the same path (in general).

To reiterate: I am **NOT** asking about whether cookies and sessions are good or bad, or whether a stateful Internet is good or bad. Therefore, the answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233946/can-we-consider-a-clients-interaction-with-a-web-server-to-be-stateful-if-the-we), while helpful, do not entirely satisfy me. I am asking whether Angular UI's `$StateProvider` creates state on the Internet, in particular the kind of state that web programmers seem to hate.

So, **should I be worried about making the Internet stateful when using Angular UI's `$StateProvider`?**

Comment: That's more about statefulness in general. I was actually thinking about asking a question like that, but thought it would be too broad.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: Luckily, it looks like my question won't be closed as a duplicate because of that phenomenon.

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon.